# Accessing built-in sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a resource for the asset store, which is the reason why (before anyone says) I cant add a resources folder, as anyone who installs the asset wont have the same folder.
Anyway, my question is simple, is there any way to access built-in sprites using code, ive managed to access some UI sprites before from an old reddit post, but they're only ones like Knob and UISprite. I need the square specifically since I'm trying to generate a square object inside the code. Ive tried using Texture2D.whiteTexture, but it doesn't work because the white texture is 4x4 pixels making it really small.

So is there a way to access the square sprite within code, or something that would also work - is there a way/function to create a square gameobject that already contains the SpriteRenderer with the square sprite (similar to just using Create>2D Object>Sprites>Square)?

Comment: Within the editor you can get all the sprites embedded and used in the Unity UI via their path .. [various people have built tools to extract them and their paths](https://gist.github.com/MattRix/c1f7840ae2419d8eb2ec0695448d4321)

Comment: You can of course also just create your own texture and then a sprite from it (`Sprite.Create`) but if I understand correctly your use case is basically creating UI content with already pre-assigned references to those built-in sprites right?

Comment: yes, I actually found a way to do it. when you use Sprite.Create() you can assign the Texture2D.whiteTexture which is a built in 4x4 white texture. Then inside of Sprite.Create() there is an argument for pixelsPerUnit, which defaults to 100 (the reason the white texture was appearing small). So i just set this to 4 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Please answer your own question by posting your comment as an answer. Don't leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Sprite.Create() with the Texture2D.whiteTexture and pixelsPerUnit argument, like this:

```
Texture2D tex = Texture2D.whiteTexture;
Sprite blankWhiteSquare = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, text.height), Vector2.zero, 4)
```